# Trying to get select link value to textbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-frontend

I have a text field and a popup link. On clicking on the popup link it displays various users from the database in a table format. I have a select link for each users. On clicking on the select link for a particular user, that username must be displayed in the text field.

Textfield code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Captain_name, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>  
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <%= f.text_field :captain_name, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

POPUP code

```
<table border="1" width="400">
  <% @user.each do |f| %>   
    <tr>  
      <td><%= f.id%></td>   
      <td><%= f.first_name %></td>  
      <td> <%= link_to "Select" %></td>   
    </tr>   
  <% end %>
```

I'm not sure how to link the text field and select link.

Comment: If I understand, you would like to dynamically populate a textfield with the username of selected users? You can't do it with Ruby, as it is a back-end language, you'll need a bit of javascript.

Comment: This is more like a front-end question, you should update your tags.

Comment: You can manually bind the variables for the two fields in JavaScript, so that values are reflected.